# understanding a super-simple function output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I dont understand why the output is like this, and not 1,3,1.

```
x = 1 
def f():
    global x
    y = x
    x = 2
    return x + y 

print x 
print f() 
print x 

##output:
##
##1
##3
##2
```

Well, i understand that 'inside' the function, `global x` tell the function to look at x whose outside the function (x=1). and then we put this x=1 into y; therefore, y=1. Now, `local x` is 2, and therefore x+y=2+1=3.

so why the last `print x` yields 2? why and how the compailer 'chose' to return the local/global x? both commands are outside the function statemante..

thanks!

Comment: the last print gives you 2 because you changed the global variable x inside the function.

Comment: timgeb:
well, i removed the line 'print f()', and now both 'print x' give the output '1'. so i guess that 'print f()' is kind of function-call? i dont get it.

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is *no* `local x`; the `global` statement makes all use of a variable in a function global.

Thus, `x = 2` alters the global `x`.

The Python compiler needs to know, up front, wether a name in a function is a local or a global name. The default is to see names as global, unless you *bind* to a name (assignment is a form of name binding), at which point *all* use of a variable in a function becomes local. You can override this behaviour with the `global` statement, which then fixes all use of a name to be global even if the name is bound.

See the the [*Naming and binding* section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) in the Python reference documentation:

> If a name is bound in a block, it is a local variable of that block.

and the [`global` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement):

> The `global` statement is a declaration which holds for the entire current code block. It means that the listed identifiers are to be interpreted as globals.

You can't treat a name as both global and local in a single scope. Use a different name instead, like you did with `y`.

Comment: I'm curious, is there a any way to unglobal x again inside the function?

Comment: @timgeb: there is not. Use a new different name.

Answer (score 1):

`global` keyword is valid for the entire block (for function body) so basically there is no local `x`. 
https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-global_stmt